# Question about javascript namespaces

Tags: javascript, namespaces

What is the point of returning methods in the following example when you can accomplish the same thing by just declaring the NS straightforward in the second code snippet?

1:

```
var NS = function() {
    return {
        method_1 : function() {
            // do stuff here
        },
        method_2 : function() {
            // do stuff here
        }
    };
}();
```

2:

```
var NS = {
    method_1 : function() { do stuff },
    method_2 : function() { do stuff }
};
```

Answer (score 11):

In your particular example there is no advantage. But you can use the first version to hide some variables:

```
var NS = function() {
    var private = 0;
    return {
        method_1 : function() {
            // do stuff here
            private += 1;
        },
        method_2 : function() {
            // do stuff here
            return private;
        }
    };
}();
```

This is referred to as a Module in Douglas Crockford's "JavaScript: The Good Parts". If you search the web you should be able to find full explanations.

Basically the only thing that creates a new variable scope in Javascript is a function, so most global abatement revolves around either using properties of an object (NS in this case) or using a function to create a variable scope (the private var in this example).